# navigator.app.exitApp() in windows phone not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have developed an app using jquery mobile and phonegap. But navigator.app.exitApp() function does not exit the app in windows phone while it does in android. What should I need to exit the app in windows phone? I am using phonegap 3.1

Comment: phonegap Devloper chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to exit my app in the backbutton handler. I have a custom backbutton handler which navigates to the previous page and sometimes runs some other functions too (hence my reason for implementing the handler in the first place as need more than `window.history.back()`. My app actually did exit when the back button handler ran `navigator.app.exitApp()` because that was thrown an exception, and the code in CordovaView.xaml.cs didn't cancel the event when an exception was thrown so it actually still worked. Not nice to rely on exceptions like that so I implemented this instead: http://blog.projectdebug.com/?p=6 which did the trick. If you're working outside of back button handler though, I don't know what to suggest, although I've read that you're not really meant to exit the app from anywhere else as its not a convention a user would expect.